# In welchen älteren literarischen Werken kommen derbe Ausdrücke vor, die heute auch noch verwendet werden?

Tags: big-list, vocabulary, literature

Goethe schreibt zum Beispiel in *Faust*, jemand werde einem anderen mit der Faust in die **Fresse** fahren, und sein *Götz von Berlichingen* erwidert anstatt sich zu ergeben, man solle ihn **im Arsche lecken**. Welche anderen derben Audrücke bzw. Flüche/Schimpfwörter kommen in „gehobener“ Literatur vor? Ist z.B. bekannt, in welchem bekannten deutschen Werk zum ersten Mal „ficken“/„fick dich“/„Schlampe“/„Fotze“/„Scheiße“ usw. vorkommt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eine konkrete Antwort für deine Beispiele kann ich zwar nicht liefern, wohl aber Möglichkeiten, selbst auf die Suche zu gehen:

Da das [DWB](http://www.dwb.uni-trier.de/), das deutsche Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm, als das erste Wörterbuch gilt, das "Schimpfwörter und *unfeine* Wörter" (Zitat Wikipedia) aufgenommen hat und es praktischerweise das umfangreichste etymologische Werk zur deutschen Sprache ist und vor Zitaten und Quellverweisen strotzt, würde ich dort einmal nach den von dir gewünschten Informationen suchen. In vielen Fällen findet sich für eine frühe Verwendung tatsächlich ein Zitat von einem bekannten Schriftsteller, die Herren Goethe, Schiller oder Lessing sind mir schon öfter über den Weg gelaufen.

Allerdings kommen dort natürlich keine modernen Ausdrücke vor - bei vielen heute vulgären Ausdrücken liegt ja eine eigentlich nichtvulgäre Bedeutung zugrunde, die nur teilweise oder ganz verloren gegangen ist. Dies ist mitunter erst im letzten Jahrhundert geschehen.

Das DWB ist leider jetzt gerade (mal wieder) nicht erreichbar, daher zitiere ich jetzt nicht daraus. Ich gebe dir aber noch den Tipp mit, dass du statt ß sz bei der Suche verwenden musst.

Ach ja, und dann kannst du natürlich noch den [Google NGram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/) verwenden, um erstmalige Verwendungen von Wörtern zu finden. Leider ist das deutschsprachige Korpus für frühere Jahrhunderte nicht sehr ausgeprägt, ab etwa dem 19. Jahrhundert findet sich dort jedoch auch relativ viel. Hier sind aber keine Bewertungen zur Bedeutung des jeweiligen Wortes zu finden, viele Wörter tauchen also eher in ihrer ursprünglichen Bedeutung auf. Auch unterschiedliche Schreibweisen werden hier nicht, wie sonst bei Google üblich, automatisch zusammengeführt, so dass ein vorheriger Blick in den Grimm hier auch Wunder wirken kann.

Answer (score 5):

Schau Dir mal "Leck mir den Arsch fein recht schön sauber" und "Leck mich im Arsch" von Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart an.

Comment: Ja, das kenn ich natürlich schon :)

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt das Buch [Ich mach's dir mexikanisch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/340651099X) von Christoph Gutknecht, welches sich quasi wie eine Dissertation zu diesem Thema liest. Es ist schon eine ganze Weile her, dass ich es gelesen habe, und ich kann es leider gerade nicht finden, aber wenn meine Erinnerung mich nicht trügt, werden dort sehr viele Quellen angegeben.

Es wird nicht explizit auf alte Begriffe eingangen, sondern zunächst die einzelnen Organe abgearbeitet, bevor es zu verschiedenen Aktionen übergeht...